# Apache high cpu usage post request

Tags: php, apache, xmlhttprequest

I have apache processes which are overloading the cpu.
I'm attaching an image of the apache server status mod on which we can see that the process which is causing the problem is a POST request.
[image]

This is a post request made by jquery `XHR-POST-REQUEST`
Do i have to exit such request somehow? Or how can i make it to not overload the cpu. 
Oh, and i forgot to mention that this is a post request for image uploads. So in the dp.php there is some image processing. Like `move_uploaded_file();` and extension checking etc.
UPDATE1: 
This is the problem
[image: Problems]

Comment: Are you resizing the image, or doing something else complicated with it? Using what library?

Comment: now that you said, there is an thumbnail creating script. maybe that is causing it?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Those operations are very expensive, especially on the CPU.

Comment: okay but that doesnt take that much... these processes arent disappearing... they are some kind of stuck there and generating load until i restart the server

Comment: Maybe whatever tool you use to do the processing hangs and causes the problem?

Comment: i will give it a try... i will remove the resize script and test it a few hours/days and see what's happening

Comment: Updated the question please take a look at it @Pekka웃